# Python module to listen for WSGI requests from Apache?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

From what I understand, Apache mod_wsgi implements a python interpreter that runs alongside Apache and serves CGI requests, but the difference between WSGI and CGI is that, with WSGI the Python session just keeps running as long as the Apache server is running whereas with CGI it has to restart every time the server gets a CGI request.

What I'd like to know is, is there a Python module that you can run separately from Apache, like in an interactive Python session, that will listen for CGI requests from Apache?  So, for instance, you can have Apache running and your WSGI middleware not running, and then you can start an interactive Python session and import your WSGI middleware module and then it will serve CGI requests from Apache, and you can also shut it down without shutting down Apache.  So it is a single session like Apache mod_wsgi, but it doesn't have to always run concurrently with Apache, and you can run it from an interactive Python session.

Edit 1:

So for instance, I have this flask app, myapp.py:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

app.apples = 0

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    app.apples += 1
    return 'blah: %d' % app.apples

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

And I can run it by typing python myapp.py, but it starts its own web server.  Instead I'd like Apache to be the web server, but I'd like to be able to open an interactive python shell and type `from myapp import *` and have app listen for requests from Apache, and since I have my interactive shell, so I can do stuff like `print app.apples` or `app.apples = 50` or whatever.  I'm saying I want my web app to be separate from the web server, and to be interactive with the python shell.

And what I mean to say with `app.apples` is that it is a global variable, like a hit count for the number of times `'/'` has been accessed, and it persists as long as the app is running.

Edit 2:

Here's another example.

myapp.py:

```
import web

def add_global_hook():
    g = web.storage({"counter": 0})
    def _wrapper(handler):
        web.ctx.globals = g
        return handler()
    return _wrapper

class Hello:
    def GET(self):
        web.ctx.globals.counter += 1
        return "<h1>Counter: %d</h1>" % web.ctx.globals.counter

urls = ("/", "Hello")
app = web.application(urls, globals())
app.add_processor(add_global_hook())
app.run()
```

Here, I can open a python interpreter and type `from myapp import *`, and it starts the web server, but while the web server is running, I'm blocked from using the interactive shell.  Is there some way to run the server in a non-blocking way so that I can use the interactive shell?

Comment: It would help if you could edit and explain why you want this -- maybe that would stir up some good ideas.

Comment: This might be useful for debugging apache+wsgi setup in case of problems. Also, I could see some use in debugging wsgi applications, and in general for providing repl for wsgi.

Comment: Yeah I'd like it for debugging, and I'd like to have Apache running separately from the interactive session, so I can shut Apache down separately but still have the interactive session there--so I can make modifications or whatever--then start Apache back up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your considered running gunicorn WSGI server with Apache as a front end proxy?

If you are after ability to debug a live Python web application without needing to do anything too complicated, also look at:

https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wsgi-shell

You would just want to make sure you use mod_wsgi daemon mode within default of single daemon process if using mod_wsgi.

BTW, your understanding of how mod_wsgi works is a bit wrong, but rather than try and correct that it would simply help that you explain better why you want to do what you are trying to do. Perhaps starting by presenting the actual problem rather than your perceived solution.

Comment: So here's the problem:  How do I make a web app separate from the web server, and interactive with the python shell?

Comment: BTW I tried out your wsgi-shell, but the embedded python console doesn't appear to have access to variables in my application.  For instance, I tried `print app.apples` from the embedded console, and it tells me 'app' is not defined, so perhaps I am misunderstanding the purpose of the embedded console.

Comment: It is a Python interpreter, you need to import modules before you can access stuff from them, so try 'import app' first.

Comment: Right, so I imported my web app in the embedded console, but it has no relation to the running instance of the web app that I connected to through the socket file.  For instance, if I access "/" in my web browser three times, then `app.apples = 3`, however when I `print app.apples` in the embedded console, I get `0`.  See how I mean I want to do live debugging on the running instance?

Comment: Your issue then may come down to how you have configured mod_wsgi then, which you haven't explained. Add debug print statments to you app module to print out __file__, __name__ and os.getpid() and then verify that same when accessing through embedded interpreter. You may not be talking to same process or even the right sub interpreter if mod_wsgi configuration is wrong.

Comment: I'm just using the Flask built-in server right now.  And it's the same process.  The print statements go like this when I start the server (in directory /srv/www/flask/):
`myapp.py
__main__
7240`
then this when I `import myapp` in the embedded console:
`/srv/www/flask/myapp.py
myapp
7240`
I do `print myapp.app.apples` and get `0` after I visit the page 3 times and the counter displays on the page as 3.

Comment: Ok, now I got it working with Web.py because with the Flask server you can't open a python shell and do `app.run()`--you get an exception.  So you have to run it from bash using python myapp.py, which means it runs with `__name__ = __main__`, while in the embedded console you import myapp and it has `__name__ = myapp`.  But with Web.py you can run the server from within the python shell by doing the import and `app.run()`, so that's what I did, and it works!  It runs with the same name.  Thank you very much Graham!

Answer (score 0):

I'm contemplating the same question since I'm having trouble figuring out why certain DLLs won't load under Windows+Apache 2.2+mod_wsgi.  (In my case, trouble when Python's Shapely library tries to load "geos_c.dll".)

The work-around I'm considering is to run a standalone WSGI app, say on port 81, that works correctly for all requests directly to that port.  THEN, configure Apache to proxy that port, with something like:

```
ProxyPass /wsgi/myapp http://127.0.0.1:81
ProxyPassReverse /wsgi/myapp http://127.0.0.1:81
```

There are some things you have be concerned about:

- the built-in WSGI server is not multithreaded (so you just threw away one big advantage of using WSGI behind Apache)
- your standalone Python WSGI server needs to be launched in a console (accidentally closing it will kill your app -- trowing away another advantage of Apache WSGI, which would serve the app as a service w/ no console and no one logged in)

Answer (score 0):

Python has a built in wsgi server in the `wsgiref` module, suitable for development and testing purposes, though probably not for production uses.  For example, using the also provided example wsgi app:

```
>>> import wsgiref.simple_server
>>> server = wsgiref.simple_server.make_server('0.0.0.0', 8888, wsgiref.simple_server.demo_app)
>>> server.serve_forever()
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jul/2016 00:44:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2664
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jul/2016 00:44:05] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 2615
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jul/2016 00:44:05] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 2675
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-5-30934a6743d8>", line 1, in <module>
    server.serve_forever()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 236, in serve_forever
    poll_interval)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 155, in _eintr_retry
    return func(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt

>>>
```